# Mongoose: use plugin in Schema static method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I use [mongoose random plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-random).
In my schema definition i call

```
GameSchema.plugin(random, { path: 'r' });
```

After that I have a custom static method who use the plugin:

```
GameSchema.statics.someMethod {  
    [...]
    GameSchema.findRandom...
```

And I get the error

```
TypeError: Object #<Schema> has no method 'findRandom'
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do or should I implement some kind of repository ?

EDIT:
Ben's answer worked, I needed to use findRandom on the model and not the schema.
Precision for those in my case: you need to declare first your static function

```
GameSchema.statics.someMethod {  
    [...]
    Game.findRandom...
```

then register your schema

```
var Game = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);
```

otherwise you'll get "Model ....  has no method 'someMethod'"
Game variable in the static function is recognized event though it is defined only later in the script.
=> bonus question: does anyone know why it works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method on the schema, whereas you need to be calling it on the model.

```
var Game = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);

Game.findRandom()...
```

Comment: It does work this way :) Just a precision: I tried that but I was putting var Game =mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema); before my static function def and therefor getting 'unknow method'. I tried again and put it at the end of the file and now it works (which is still a little odd to me as Game var is not defined when I use it in the static method).